# JSON parsing issue : Getting only one Array

Tags: android

My JSON array contains TWO array data (weekid = 16 and weekid = 15). But When I parse, I am only getting one (weekid = 16). Unable to get (weekid = 15). Thanks 
in advance.

Below is my code :

```
private JSONArray data = null;

JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url, "GET", params, false);

try {

                    data = json.getJSONArray(data);


                    if(data.getJSONObject(0).isNull(TAG_NO_NEW_MESSAGES)){
                        Log.d("DataJson * ", json.toString());

                        //Log.d("DataJson", String.valueOf(data.length()));
                        // looping through All messages
                        for (int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject c = data.getJSONObject(i);

                            String dataone = null;

                            dataone = c.getString("data");
                            Log.d("data", "data: " + data); //HERE ONLY GETTING 16 NOT 15)
}
```

Comment: it is becoz of your this condition
                    if(data.getJSONObject(0).isNull(TAG_NO_NEW_MESSAGES)){

Comment: Can't find anything wrong with your code. Try setting some breakpoints. Is data.length() 1 or 2? Are you sure that's the JSON you posted?